# Capture all groups that fit regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a regex that does pretty much exactly what I want: `\.?(\w+[\s|,]{1,}\w+[\s|,]{1,}\w+){1}\.?`

Meaning it captures incidences of 3 words in a row that are not separated by anything except spaces and commas (so parts of sentences only). However I want this to match *every* instance of 3 words in a sentence.

So in this ultra simple example:

`Hi this is Bob.`

There should be 2 captures - "Hi this is" and "this is Bob". I can't seem to figure out how to get the regex engine to parse the entire statement this way. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can get two matches with [`(?=\b(\w+(?:[\s,]+\w+){2})\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/yC5dG5/2) and get the text you need from Group 1.

Comment: Strictly speaking, maybe not, but either with a loop or some special function, you can do it. What language are you using?

Comment: !!! @stribizhev that's the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just get overlapping texts in capturing groups, but you can obtain overlapping *matches* with capturing groups holding the substrings you need.

Use

```
(?=\b(\w+(?:[\s,]+\w+){2})\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC5dG5/2)

The unanchored positive lookahead tests for an empty string match at every position of a string. It does not consume characters, but can still return submatches obtained with capturing groups.

Regex breakdown:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\w+(?:[\s,]+\w+){2})` - 3 "words" separated with `,` or a whitespace.

  - `\w+` - 1 or more alphanumeric symbols followed with
  - `(?:[\s,]+\w+){2}` - 2 sequences of 1 or more whitespaces or commas followed by 1 or more alphanumeric symbols.

This pattern is just put into a capturing group `(...)` that is placed inside the lookahead `(?=...)`.

Word boundaries are important in this expression because `\b` prevents matching *inside* a word (between two alphanumeric characters). As the lookahead is not anchored it tests *all* positions inside input string, and `\b` serves as a restriction on where a match can be returned.

In C#, you just need to collect all `match.Groups[1].Value`s, e.g. like this:

```
var s = "Hi this is Bob.";
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"(?=\b(\w+(?:[\s,]+\w+){2})\b)")
                        .Cast<Match>()
                        .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
                        .ToList();
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Fqc7M9)

Comment: Hi @stribizhev, how does word boundary work within this solution? Does it mean that for every word found in the target string, check for the following condition (the following condition being a word followed by 2 incidences of a space and a word)?

Comment: I added some explanation of how word boundaries work here. The first one is especially important since it forces the look-ahead to only return matches found at a word boundary.

Comment: If anyone in the future tries to use this regex pattern in .NET - I had to access the matches via `foreach ( Match match in matches) { var words = match.Groups[1].ToString().Split(' '); }`

Comment: @CBauer: If you use C#, you should have indicated it from the beginning. I could show you how to use it. I have updated the answer with corresponding code in C#.